# Using toupper on char returns the ascii number of the char, not the character?

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{

char hmm[1000];

cin.getline(hmm, 1000);
cout << hmm << endl;    //this was to test if I could assign my input to the array properly
for (int sayac = 0; hmm[sayac] != '@'; sayac++) {
    if (!isdigit(hmm[sayac])) {
        if (islower(hmm[sayac])) 
            cout << toupper(hmm[sayac]);
        else if (isupper(hmm[sayac]))
            cout << tolower(hmm[sayac]);
        else
            cout << hmm[sayac];
    }
}
```

"Write a program that reads keyboard input to the @ symbol and that echoes the input
except for digits, converting each uppercase character to lowercase, and vice versa.
(Don’t forget the cctype family.) "

I'm doing this exercise from the primer book. But when I run it, it returns the ascii order of the char, not the uppercase/lowercase version of the character. Couldn't figure out the problem. Can someone tell my why please?

(I may have other problems about the exercise, please don't correct them if I have. I want to fix it on my own (except the problem I explained), but I can't check the other ones as I have this problem.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: yes, it [does](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) (in a sense)

Comment: In C++ there is no character type, there are just integer types that are conventionally used to represent characters. Some i/o facilities, in particular the narrow iostreams, will interpret `char` values as denoting characters. The global `toupper` is a function inherited from old C, it takes an `int` argument and returns an `int`. To display that character via `cout`, cast it to `char`. Note that the argument to `toupper` must be non-negative or else `EOF`, which means that a `char` value as argument should be cast to `unsigned char` first. Or else, likely UB. Also, call `setlocale` first.

Comment: Side note: +1 for having made an attempt, got all the information, and then explicitly asking for help ONLY on the issue rather than any others.  You sir, I am sure, will learn lots about the language fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When writing

```
std::cout << toupper('a');
```

the following happen:

1. [`int toupper(int ch)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) is called, and returns an integer whose value is `'A'` (`0x41`).
2. [`std::basic_ostream::operator<<(std::cout, 0x41)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) is called, that is the `int` (2) overload since an `int` was provided.

Overall, it prints "65".

As a solution, you can cast back your upper case to a `char`:

```
std::cout << static_cast<char>(toupper('a'));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a question of representation. There is no difference between a character and that character's numeric value. It's all in how you choose to display it. For example, the character '`a`' is just a constant with a value equal to the character's numeric value.

The problem you are having is that [`std::toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) and [`std::tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) return an `int` rather than a `char`. One reason for that is that they handle `EOF` values, which are not necessarily representable by `char`. As a consequence, `std::cout` see you are trying to print an `int` and not a `char`. The standard behavior for streaming an `int` is to print the number. The solution is then to cast your result to `char` to force the value to be interpreted as a character. You can use something like `std::cout << static_cast<char>(std::toupper(hmm[sayac]));`.

Try the following :

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char hmm[1000];

    std::cin.getline(hmm, 1000);
    std::cout << hmm << std::endl;    //this was to test if I could assign my input to the array properly
    for (int sayac = 0; hmm[sayac] != '@'; sayac++) {
        if (!std::isdigit(hmm[sayac])) {
            if (std::islower(hmm[sayac]))
                std::cout << static_cast<char>(std::toupper(hmm[sayac]));
            else if (isupper(hmm[sayac]))
                std::cout << static_cast<char>(std::tolower(hmm[sayac]));
            else
                std::cout << hmm[sayac];
        }
    }
}
```

You should also consider using an `std::string` instead of an array of `char` of arbitrary length. Also, take note that you have undefined behavior if the input string does not contain `@`.

Comment: thanks for the help. why I wanted to use a char array is the book didn't teached about strings yet (even though I know enough to use it here) so I wanted to to the exercise with what the book offered until now